# What does this bowing marking signify?

Tags: notation, violin, bowing

In Maurice Ravel's String Quartet in F Major, just before the up-bow marking, the engraver has written what looks like an upside-down down-bow marking.

I have not come across this before …. What does it mean?

[image: Score for string quartet, showing an upside-down down-bow marking.]

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal down-bow. For some reason the publisher, Durand, seems to invert down-bow markings in certain scores.